# If I work directly on a server, is it possible to save a copy on my machine and continue on localhost?

Tags: ubuntu, server, localhost

This question might seem ridiculous, but I'm a newbie with *lot of doubts*.

Currently I'm working on a website project in python (with some external python libraries) and I'm operating directly on Ubuntu Server 16.10 without first deploying from my machine (localhost). If I changed my mind and would like to save a copy of the server on my machine and work first on localhost,  am I able to do that?
If yes, how?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if you're able to copy files from one computer to another.  Yes, you are able to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I do it?

Comment: How can you do *what*, exactly?  Copy files from one computer to another?  There are *many* ways.  How do you *currently* copy files to the server?  Seems like that would be a reasonable approach for copying files *from* the server.

Comment: This was the confirmation I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to backup your work to your local machine , or preferably to some version control system such as github. This will give you peace of mind that your work wont get lost.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How can I do it?

Comment: if you are using python with pip packages, I highly recommend you use virtualenv, that way when you install packages, they stay related to your local application only. Then use pip freeze > requirements.txt to create a list of dependencies. You can deploy these back to your local machine and run them without any conflicts.